# Manually adding text to html.ValidationSummary?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, modelstate

I am rather new to mvc2 and when following a writeup on data annotations and such, I came across a bit of code that let me manually add a line of text to the validation summary.

I've searched for the last 2 or 3 hours and I've come to the point where I think I'm just searching for the wrong thing. Its not custom validators I'm looking for, but something that I can call from the controller to add error messages.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

edit: clarified title a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("*", "There was an error processing your request")
```

MSDN - [ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470583%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
MSDN - [Validating Model Data in an MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410404%28VS.90%29.aspx)

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had tried that before but was apparently using it incorrectly. Thank you very much!